# Select all and adding a new column if has certain value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a `platforms` table that has `id`, `name` and `parent_id` and other columns.

Is it possible to write a query that selects all `platforms` from the table, and if it has a `parent_id` which is not `0`, an extra column gets added which has the `parent_name`?

Like:

```
id    name    parent_id
2     pl1     0
3     pl2     0
4     pl3     2
```

And the desired query would yield:

```
id    name    parent_id    parent_name
2     pl1     0
3     pl2     0
4     pl3     2            pl1
```

Comment: Are here already is `parent_name` column? Or It should be automatically added?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using a `left join`:

```
select p.*, pp.name as parent_name
from platforms p left join
     platforms pp
     on p.parent_id = pp.id;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but small mistake (at least I think it is), when using p.name, it selects the name of the child, not the parent. It should be pp.name as parent_name.

Comment: @Alexey . . . That was actually a typo.  It is now `pp`.